# initialization of string in struct

Tags: c

```
struct Person{
  char *name;
  int numb;
  char *var;
};

struct Node{
   struct Person *data;
   struct Node *next;
   struct Node *prev;
};


int main() {

head=(struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));//
tail=(struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));//These two are global variables and they are initialized with null above.

 struct Person *a1=(struct Person*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Person)));
 char is[]="nameee";
 strcpy(a1->name,is);

 printf("%s\n",a1->name);



  return 0;
}
```

why i am getting segmentation fault for that code? I created a doubly linked list stored Person but when i initialized the structure with a string this code is getting an error.

Comment: Do not cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: `a1->name` is an uninitialised value. You need to allocate dynamic memory or declare that as a fixed size char array.

Comment: You have not allocated any space for `a1->name`

Comment: It did not work. I removed (struct Person*) but still getting an error. I am new in c so can you explain a little more.@Tordek

Comment: My comment was not meant as a solution but as a good practice. By casting the return value of `malloc` you're hiding potential bugs, and obscuring code unnecessarily.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce], a complete compilable program. Casting the return value of malloc and *not* having includes can **exactly** cause crashes too. If you do not provide the code I am going to assume that's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Person *a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
char is[] = "nameee";
strcpy(a1->name,is);
```

`strcpy` copies a string into a memory location (in this case, `a1->name`); it needs to be allocated. `a1->name`'s value is uninitialized, thus you are writing in an undefined location in memory.

You need to allocate space for it, for example like:

```
struct Person *a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
char is[] = "nameee";
a1->name = malloc(strlen(is) + 1);
strcpy(a1->name,is);
```

or, use `strdup`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not allocating memory for `a1->name`. Sure, you're allocating memory for `a1`, which includes the pointer `a1->name`, but `name` is not pointing anywhere valid. You need to allocate memory for that, too:

```
a1->name = malloc(sizeof("nameee"));
```

And don't forget to free all your memory when you're done:

```
free(a1->name);
free(a1);
free(head);
free(tail);
```

---

> These two are global variables and they are initialized with null
>   above.

To have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is i helpful if you include parts like that in your code, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    struct Person *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} *head, *tail;
```

Comment: *and* #includes...

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. This is not related under the topic but i wonder that if i initialize header with malloc. The types of the node class are initialized NULL? And also i have created the head with struct Node* head=NULL so what if i do struct Node head=NULL these two are different? I am new on c and these type of questions are confusing.@Blaze

Comment: @XY `head` is just a pointer. When you assign to it with `head=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` it overwrites the value it previously had. With `struct Node head=NULL` you're making a pointer and setting its value to `NULL`, but it's not allocating any memory for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

a1->name is not initialized, you should malloc it or change it to an array like

````
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 30

struct Person{
  char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
  int numb;
  char *var;
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating a variable of type `struct Person`. The field `name`is just a pointer. But there is no space allocated for the string that `name` points to.

You need to allocate the string itself, something like: `a1->name = malloc(xxx);`