# initialization of malloc for struct type

Tags: c

```
struct Person{
  char *name;
  int numb;
  char *var;
};
```

i have created a person above.

```
struct Person *per1=malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
char per1_name[]="leo";
per1->name=malloc(strlen(per1_name)+1);
strcpy(per1->isim,per1_name);
per1->numb=12;
char per1_var[]="Twitter";
per1->var=malloc(strlen(per1_var)+1);
strcpy(per1->var,per1_var);
```

and i always initialize it like that as you can see it is so long, so is there any easy way for intialization of struct type that contains string?

Comment: What's `per1->isim`? And your struct type does not contain any strings. It contains pointers to strings. This is how you declared it.

Comment: Actually, i have used this first but this problem has occured. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951732/initialization-of-string-in-struct/58951829?noredirect=1#comment104160732_58951829   @AnT

Comment: Because of the requirement for dynamic allocation of two members, no, there isn't a short way to do this. Were those fixed buffers you could declare a struct with initial values, malloc a dynamic struct, then simply use struct-assignment. But, this is the road you chose, so...

Comment: I got it. Thanks @WhozCraig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that initializes your struct:

```
void InitializePerson(struct Person *person, const char* name, int number, const char* var)
{
  person->name = strdup(person);
  person->var = strdup(var);
  person->numb = number;
}

int main()
{
  struct Person* per1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
  InitializePerson(per1, "leo", 12, "Twitter");
}
```

This is just one of many possibilities. Also note that there is no error checking whatsoever for brevity.

if [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) is not available on your platform, you can write your own, it's basically 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use macro to simplify/shorten your code.
Also you can use separate function which initializes your structure.

```
struct Person{
  char *name;
  int numb;
  char *var;
};


#define MK_PERSON(per1, name, var, numb) \
struct Person *per1=malloc(sizeof(struct Person));\
per1->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);\
strcpy(per1->name,name);\
per1->numb=numb;\
per1->var=malloc(strlen(var)+1);\
strcpy(per1->var,var);


struct Person * mk_person(const char *name, const char *var, int numb){
    struct Person *per1=malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    per1->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(per1->name,name);
    per1->numb=numb;
    per1->var=malloc(strlen(var)+1);
    strcpy(per1->var,var);
    return per1;
}

int main(){

MK_PERSON(pers1, "Bob","m", 12);

struct Person *pers2 = mk_person("Mike", "m", 13);

}
```

this way you make/test and debug initialization only once and can use it safely later while being sure that everything is ok.

I recommend to use function instead macro.

Comment: Why use a macro in the first place?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, OP should know all possible ways to shoot himself into the foot :-)